# Big O for DynamicArray vs HashTable while fetching their values using their indexes

Tags: c#, data-structures, hashtable, dynamic-arrays

In general, I know that Hashtables have better performance when compared to dynamic arrays for searching a particular value. Does this hold true when we are fetching the value directly by passing in an index?

E.g.:

```
HashTable d=new HashTable(); //let us consider it is initialized with values 

for (int i = 0; i < largeValue ; i++)
        {
            int doNothing=d[i];
        }
```

versus:

```
DynamicArray l=new DynamicArray(); //let us consider it is initialized with values

 for (int i = 0; i < largeValue ; i++)
        {
            int doNothing=l[i];
        }
```

Which one has better performance?

Edit 1: I have Edited the question based on  the comments.

Comment: Your bottleneck is by a factor >1000 the Console.WriteLine call. If you replace that with something fast then the List will win because the lookup is cheaper because for the Hashtable the Hashcode and Equality check needs to be performed.

Comment: A straight search to find an item on average has to search N/2 items in the list.  So if you have 1 million items you have to search 0.5 million items.  A hash is a binary tree so the number of items is the log 2 of N = 20.  So 20 << 500,000.

Comment: I am unsure if Dictionary works like a hashtable. I asume that Hashtable is what works like a Hashtable. Plus for optimized searching depending on the type, you would propably need stuff like a B-Tree (or whatever else Database indexes use for that type).

Comment: @Christopher I am trying to find whether Dynamic Array gives a better performance when fetching value  compared to a  HashTable by directly using indexes instead of searching for the value,I have modified my question for a better understanding

Comment: @jdweng In here we are not searching for the particular value but trying get a value  through a given index and I also thought for searching a value in hashtable, we calculate the hash value of  the given value and return it directly through its hashValue which takes O(1) instead of going through all the items present in HashTable

Comment: I given index is just a simple add.  So performance is one.

Comment: @MANOJVARMA: So this boils down to a "Wich is faster" question? If so, I need to link the speed rant: https://ericlippert.com/2012/12/17/performance-rant/

Answer (score 0):

Dictionary lookups will be slower even though both operations are O(1). Indexing into a predefined array memory location (the data structure Lists are built from) involves fewer operations; most likely, it's a matter of finding the beginning of the memory block and adding the index offset.

[Hashtable](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hash_table) lookups, on the other hand, are amortized O(1). Depending on how the hashtable is implemented, you'll need to compute a potentially complex hashcode, index into a bucket, walk part of a linked list pointed to by the bucket, and check equality to ensure that the item you've located matches the one you're after. This is a lot more work than a list index operation.

Two operations may be in the same time complexity category (in this case O(1)), but may have radically different constant factor on the work they perform. Such is the case here.

Take a look at [Dictionary part 2, .NET implementation](https://blog.markvincze.com/back-to-basics-dictionary-part-2-net-implementation/) if you'd like to explore the workings of C# dictionaries further.